# How do i break a page based on the supplier ID?

Tags: ms-access

How do i insert a page break based on the records extracted which is grouped by Supplier?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUeF2.png)

I've tried to do a force page break(before section) and view it via print preview, it breaks every single record. is there something i'm missing here?

Sql Statment is here:

```
SELECT PRODUCTDETAILS.Title, SUPPLIER.Supplier, SUPPLIER.EMail, 
    PURCHASEORDER.POID, Purchaseorderchild.Productid, 
    Purchaseorderchild.Qty, PURCHASEORDER.POID, PURCHASEORDER.Date
FROM SUPPLIER INNER JOIN (
    PURCHASEORDER INNER JOIN (
        PRODUCTDETAILS INNER JOIN Purchaseorderchild 
            ON PRODUCTDETAILS.productID = Purchaseorderchild.Productid
        ) ON PURCHASEORDER.POID = Purchaseorderchild.POID
    ) ON SUPPLIER.SupplierID = PRODUCTDETAILS.SupplierID
WHERE (((PURCHASEORDER.POID)=[Please Enter Purchase Order No]))
GROUP BY SUPPLIER.Supplier;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a Grouping section for `Supplier`, with header.

Then you can set the `Section.ForceNewPage` property for that header section.

Comment: Thanks i somehow managed to make it to work. but the even pages seem to have the section highlighted am i able to remove that highlight?
and also how am i able to reset the S/No. on each page break?

Comment: @SamuelNg: Set the `Section.AlternateBackColor` property to "No color" or the same color as `BackColor`. For S/No. please ask a new question with more details on that field.

Comment: Right now when the supplier changes the S/No Column doesn't reset upon page break. so for example i have 4 records on the first page, it will show 1-4 and then on the 2nd page it with show 5 onwards and not reset to 1 again. is there a way i can force a reset on that field every page break based on the supplier?

Comment: Again, this is a new question. In there, show the control source of that field.

Comment: managed to solve it thanks alot. i just needed to change the value to running sum over group and its done.